# C- Incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I've a problem and I don't understand why compiler says me this warning:

> Incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int [2][2]'

```
int matrice[2][2]={4,7,3,6};
int* prova2=matrice;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
printf("%d",*(prova2+i));
}
```

Logically, it works but I want to know why the IDE show me that.
I've tried to do the same with an array but it works without any warning.

I know that when I declare an array like

```
int a[4];
```

a contains the address where the array is allocated in memory.
So, there aren't differences (type differences) between

```
int a[4];
```

or

```
int *b= a;
```

Why are there differences between

```
int matrice[2][2]
```

and

```
int* prova2=matrice;
```

?

Comment: `int matrice[2][2]={{4,7},{3,6}};` or `int matrice[4]={4,7,3,6};`.

Comment: "a contains the address where the array is allocated in memory" <- Wrong! `int a[4];` means that a contains 4 ints, and `int *b` means that b contains an address.

Comment: It's strange that the "array-pointer equivalence" myth still survives, after almost half a century of C. I guess that it's passed down from one generation of novices who know better than old people to the next.

Comment: @immibis But I know that    int A[] can be converted to int* A . So I can use the name of the array like a pointer

Comment: Maybe, you don't understand perfectly what I've asked. With int vettore[4]={5,10,7,8}; int *ptr=vettore; I don't receive warning even if vettore is of int[4] type and ptr a pointer to int. With int matrice[3][3]={1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17} ; int *mat=matrice; Compiler says me that i'm trying to point a pointer to integer with a int[3][3]. Why this differences?

Comment: @ndPPPhz `int *mat = matrice;` is **short for** `int *mat = &matrice[0];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array of T` can be converted to `T*`. `matrice` is an array of `int[2]`, so it can be implicitly converted to `pointer to int[2]`, that is you can write:

```
int (*prova2)[2] = matrice;
```

(But that's obviously not what you want).

To get the pointer to the first element you can just do:

```
int* prova2 = &matrice[0][0];
```

Comment: @immibis But I know that int A[] can be converted to int* A . So I can use the name of the array like a pointer – ndPPPhz 13 mins ago    
     
Maybe, you don't understand perfectly what I've asked. With int vettore[4]={5,10,7,8}; int *ptr=vettore; I don't receive warning even if vettore is of int[4] type and ptr a pointer to int. With int matrice[3][3]={1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17} ; int *mat=matrice; Compiler says me that i'm trying to point a pointer to integer with a int[3][3]. Why this differences?

Comment: Well it's quite simple: the first address of vettore contains an integer correct? However the first address of matrice doesn't contain an integer but an array of 3 integers. Therefore the dereferencing mat, *mat, will not produce an integer as the variable type declaration. Dereferencing mat will in fact return a pointer to an array of 3 integers.